# Htaccess редирект

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Как правильно прописать код в `.htaccess`, чтобы ссылка

```
site.ru/test?theme=normal
```

редиректила на

```
site.ru/test
```

**Обновление**

Надо, чтобы все ссылки, оканчивающиеся на `?theme=normal`, редиректили на нормальный адрес.
Грубо говоря, вот таким кодом я убираю слеш в конце url:

```
--------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
--------------------------------------------
```

Как его правильно исправить, чтобы удалялся `?theme=normal`?

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect 301 test http://site.ru/test?theme=normal
```

Если правильно понял вас.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы исключить строку параметров нужно поставить знак вопроса в конце. Таким образом мы определяем свою строку параметров.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://site.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```